# show image from esternal card gives java.lang.nulPointer Exception

Tags: android, bitmap

i have this snippet to retieve an image from an sd car card but all i get is java.lang.nullPointerException:

```
try {

                     BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                      options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                      options.inSampleSize = 2;
                      options.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024];
                      options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/monImage.png", options);
                      image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    //  selected_photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selected_photo);
                      /*String photoPath="/"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/monImage.png";
                      Uri photoUri = Uri.parse(photoPath);
                                              image.setImageBitmap(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),photoUri));*/


                  }
                  catch (Exception e){Log.d("merde>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", "grrrrr " +e);}
```

I have tried many oder solutions but still, i always have the same problem even when i change the image file. And when i change the file name to give a false one, it tells me that file not found :(

can anyone help?? i've seen others having the same problem but didn't see anysolution that worked for me

Comment: remove .toString() from Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() and try it.

Comment: i did but still the same null pointer exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it and this works for me:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/monImage.png");
```

If you have more problems you may want to the state of the external storage:

```
boolean mExternalStorageAvailable, mExternalStorageWriteable;
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
{   mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
}
else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) 
{   mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
}
else 
{   mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
    mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
}
```